# Is knowing someone's card expiration date a means of finding info about them?

Tags: privacy, credit-card

Card as in debit or credit cards. I heard that even showing someone your debit/CC can be considered an exploit not because of the number or name, but because of the date of expiration. He said that working backwards from that date they can tell exactly when it was first issued and can keep going from there on. I wanted to know if this is a real concern or just a hunch.

Can expiration dates on cards really give way for one to find more info about a person? I believe the date working backwards thingy is true.

Answer (score 2):

No. The date on the card is set by the issuer. So the length of time can be different from vendor to vendor. Even might be different depending on the card or account type. So you would have to know exactly what that time frame is to get the issue date. The issue date is also not a security question at financial institutions to verify the identity of a customer. Whereas the expiration date itself might be. But not enough on it's own. So phishing would be an unlikely use for the date unless you already had additional information about the customer. (IE Last 4 of social, last deposit amount, account number, other information about that card, etc) All of which are impossible to get from the date.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like aggrandizing (or maybe paranoia), technically someone can only use it to narrow down when the card was issued, but no places that I know of use the expiration date or the issue date for any sort of standalone verification so alone it is quite worthless.

You can't tell when it was first issued since a replacement out of cycle (say if you lost your card) resets the date, and I for one have replaced every card in my wallet at least once due to loss so looking through my cards' expiration dates would tell you nothing about me except maybe the months in which I am forgetful about where my cards are. If you really wanted to know when it was issued, some banks still use the "member since xx/xx" on their cards, which is a clearer way to get at a rather useless piece of information.

I suppose one possible exploit would be to start going through the target's mail a month or two ahead of the expiration with the hopes of lifting the replacement that's sent, but that's a pretty long con. Far more important, if you are glancing at the card, are those epic last [four](http://www.wired.com/2012/08/apple-amazon-mat-honan-hacking/) [digits](https://medium.com/@N/how-i-lost-my-50-000-twitter-username-24eb09e026dd#.2x4dhg5o3).

Answer (score 0):

The expiration date tells you that the card was issued in that month within the last five years (one of five possible values). The expiration date by itself does not tell you much, and certainly far less than the average Facebook profile leaks about you.

It does not leak your postal code (often required for unattended purchases), your PIN, your CVV, the last four of your Social Security Number, when you initially established the account, what type of card it is (Visa/MasterCard/etc), your spending habits, your preferences, or ... well, anything at all. Any bank that you might try to verify stuff with is going to need more than the expiration date of one of your cards before they'll let you do anything damaging.